# Restrict User's Choice in Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, column-validation

I want to allow my users to only select either the 14th or the 28th of any month when they make a selection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that's a good question.  I had a look around for 10 mins and didn't find something that matches up with what you want, but I did find something you could try to tinker with.

@Mike Smith, a well known contributor to this site, has an interesting post on Date fields - [see here](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html).

If it were possible to combine both of the formulae Mike has posted below then it could work; instead of selecting the last day and first day of the month, you'd need to insert your own values of 14th & 28th.

[image: Date field screen shot]

Also on the same web page is this - you can specify two values using the OR function.  This could be complicated though, I searched around for something that would be flexible enough to allow a 'floating day date'.  Calculations can sometimes be done on Date fields by using DD / MM / YY calculations to 'split out' the dayday / monthmonth / yearyear values.  In your case you'd need to split out where dayday = 14 or 28.

[image: OR function pic]

Hopefully someone can suggest something that works right away, but I thought I'd offer a couple of avenues for further exploration.

### OTHER NOTES

If it doesn't *have* to be a date field, you could [create a choice column](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2) instead - simply define the column values available as 14th and 28th.

Then if you need a column to indicate the month, just create a new column called month and add in the values to pick from.